# How to submit form data to my database when port forwarding

Tags: php, mysql, forms, portforwarding

I'm developing a simple registration form. I was able to have it functional locally via localhost. I am able to receive the data placed in the inputs and store into my **phpmyadmin**.

Here's my PHP code:

```
if($boolen){

        $dbname = "regdb";
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","",$dbname);

        if(!$con){
                die("Connection Failed :" + mysqli_connect_error());
            }

        function NewUser(){
            $sql = "INSERT INTO regi (urname,email,passwd,fname,gender) VALUES ('$_POST[urname]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[passwd]','$_POST[fname]','$_POST[gender]')";

            $query = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['con'],$sql);

            if($query){
                echo "<script>
                    alert ('Record Inserted Successfully...!');
                </script>";
            }
        }

        function SignUP(){
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM regi WHERE urname = '$_POST[urname]' AND email = '$_POST[email]'";

            $result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['con'],$sql);

            if(!$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                NewUser();
            }else{
                echo "<script>
                    alert ('You Are Already Registered User......!');
                </script>";
            }
        }

        if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

            SignUp();
            mysqli_close($GLOBALS["con"]);
            $boolen = false;
        }    
    }
```

Once I port forwarded my html/php files everything seemed fine until I tried submitting the data in the inputs. It only receives the data in the inputs locally, but when I port forward it doesn't receive nothing. I get no errors.

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Show how you define your portforwarding.

Comment: Is the forwarded port default? If not you have to specify it in mysqli_connect("localhost:3306","root","",$dbname); where 3306 should be replaced with your actual port number.

Comment: You dont store nothing in phpmyadmin, you store in your db. Phpmyadmin is just a web client to mysql